# Transpose of a matrix taking ' as copyright symbol in Octave returning error

Tags: octave

For some reason when I add ' to transpose a matrix, Octave (GUI) (5.2.0) takes copyright symbol (©) as input and return an error. However this doesn't happen when directly executed in the Octave (CLI). I have tried all combination with brackets like `(error)')`  and `(error')`  . Everything seems to replace the apostrophe with © .

[1[image: 2]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are typing a right single-quote there, not the normal `'`. How have you set up your GUI? What is your OS? Did you enable some of your OS's options to automatically insert "smart quotes" in editors?

Comment: What is your language and keyboard setting in Windows ?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm running Windows10 64 bit. I downloaded Octave GUI from here - https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html  and installed from "octave-5.2.0_1-w64-installer.exe ". No I haven't touched any OS options ever. Don't even have any idea how to do so to be honest.

Comment: @matzeri My keyboard settings should be default as I have never touched them. My input language is English(India)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with V5.2 - Here is my fix,

1. Start Octave with elevated privileges
2. Menu -> Edit -> Preferences
3. On the 'Editor' tab, scroll all the way to the bottom.
4. Change all 'Fonts' to 'Courier New'
5. Apply, Exit and restart Octave.

Somehow the font(s) get changed, I think when you update to a new version.